# What is an appropriate architecture for creating a multi-user client-server application?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am developing an application that entails a single server, and a large number of clients.  I'm utilizing the Java socket programming APIs to accomplish this task.  At the moment, I am considering restructuring the entire design of my application because I simply do not think that it is structured in the most efficient way, and would appreciate some guidance towards an optimal path.

### Current Implementation

I have one `ServerSocket` located on port 5000, and the thread that contains the socket simply runs continuously and accepts any connection.  It then starts up a new server thread (based on a synchronized table of available ports) that handles communication with that client, and then blocks for `ServerSocket.accept()` again.

The threads that are spawned from this main thread also contain a `ServerSocket` and are used as a means to handle multiple connections at once.

Now, the client thread simply connects to port 5000, receives the next available port as a reply, then disconnects from port 5000 (by calling `Socket.close()`), and reconnects to the port that the server said was available.

### My Question

Is this the most optimal way (or better yet, is it even reasonable?) to handle multiple clients on a single server?  Or should I simply open `ServerSocket`'s on all available ports and just listen constantly?  Perhaps something that I have not yet considered?

### Addendum

I'm trying to think in terms of very large client-server applications such as MMORPGs or some chat application to get a feeling for my implementation's feasibility.  For example, I try to ask myself: "Although this might work, would it be a good solution if this application had a large user-base?".  That being said, it would be easier for me to understand the optimal nature of a solution if I could see how it would work on a large scale, with say, millions of users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand why you would need to use a new ServerSocket each time the main one accepts a connection. Why don't you simply use the socket returned by `accept()` (as explained in the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html))?

Also, instead of starting a new thread for each client, you should use a thread pool. This would avoid constant creations of new threads, and would avoid starting too many threads and bring your server to its knees.

This architecture is not the best one to handle a huge number of users, though. Using asynchronous IO would probably be a better solution if you really need such a scalability, but I don't have much experience with that.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply!  The reason I do not use the socket returned by `accept()` method is because my initial `ServerSocket` is only listening on port 5000.  This is where I've had much confusion regarding the theory behind `ServerSocket`'s.  Does the `accept()` method return a socket on a different port?  Otherwise, aren't we supporting multiple clients on the same port?  Is this not bad practice?  Thanks again!

Comment: The tutorial say: *The accept method waits until a client starts up and requests a connection on the host and port of this server. When a connection is requested and successfully established, the accept method returns a new Socket object which is bound to the same local port and has its remote address and remote port set to that of the client. The server can communicate with the client over this new Socket and continue to listen for client connection requests on the original ServerSocket.* It's the normal way to do things. Web servers handle many concurrent requests on port 80, for example.

Comment: I appreciate your attempts to clarify this for me. Let me paraphrase to ensure that I am understanding correctly:

The `ServerSocket` takes all requests on that IP/port pair and `accept()`'s them, binds them to the port that the server is listening on, and then continues to listen on the original port.

It appears that this would work for web servers, but if I was trying to set up a server for a networked game that required **much** data to be sent back and forth, wouldn't there be an advantage to giving each client their own port?  That is what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: It will work just fine. Don't worry about that. It's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Fair enough.  Although it would be a luxury to understand why this works, for the sake of keeping this simple I shall pursue that in my own time.  Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket: Each TCP session is identified by a 4-tuple, containing the client and server IP address + port. So even if the same server and port is used for all clients, they all differ due to the IP address and port of the clients.

Comment: Thanks again.  It is apparent that I was under a false understanding of how socket connections actually worked.

Answer (score 3):

When thinking of server architecture, the first question is to estimate how much memory and precessing power is required for single connection. The second is the number of simultaneous connections. After multiplication, we can decide if single machine is sufficient or we need a cluster.

Then we decide if we can afford a thread (some 128..512 KBytes) for a connection. If we can, then classic one-thread per-connection is OK. If we cannot, then async architecture based on NIO or NIO2 is more suitable.

After the basic decisions are done, we can select appropriate libraries and frameworks. Doing everything from scratch is more interesting, but would take so much time that the result may be interesting to nobody at the moment it is achieved.

Comment: Thank you Alexei.  This is a very good process for deciding on a Server architecture, and is something I'll have to take into consideration in pursuing this concept.  The question I had related more closely to how the ports are assigned, however I did have some doubts as to what could actually be done on a single machine.  You have helped clear some of these doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your following suggestion because the single server on port 5000 is a bottleneck:

> Or should I simply open ServerSocket's on all available ports and just
>   listen constantly?

I prefer the pool of serversocket.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I do realize that this causes a bottleneck in my application, and will probably take the approach of multiple listeners to alleviate this issue in the future.  For now, I think I will pursue what both you and JB Nizet suggested: using pools of threads to handle the sockets.

Comment: How would like to manage telling the clients were to connect to, if the server listens on more than one specific port (if not by using this two phase approach on protcol level as described by the OP)? The latter will most certainly compensate any performance gained by having the server listen on multiple ports in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Use [JMS (in my case its ActiveMq)](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/getting-started.html) achieve you target. You can have load balancing and fail over easily

Comment: Thank you for the additional resource.  I will have to look into using JMS to achieve my goal.  I had actually not been aware of this tool until now.